# How to trigger email? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I would like to trigger a mailer 'action' in a @post view.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "example@gmail.com"

  def newsletter(post)
    @greeting = ""
    @users = User.all
    @users.each do |user|
      mail to: user.email, subject: post.title
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
  = button_to 'Deliver' do
    UserMailer.newsletter(@post).deliver
  end
```

If I press this button it pops up the error "No route matches posts/6" when it's clearly exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write an action, which will call UserMailer.newsletter(@post).deliver

```
def send_newsletter
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  UserMailer.newsletter(@post).deliver
  render :nothing => true 
end
```

Add the necessary route, and link the button to that action

In routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    get :send_newsletter
  end
end
```

In view

```
link_to 'Deliver', send_newsletter_post_path(@post)
```

Further, you can change get method to post and submit a form for sending the newsletter

Comment: Wow, that definitely looks like the Rails way. Thanks.